# Dynamics variables in smarty in loop

Tags: smarty

How can i generate dynamics variable names in smarty?

I trying using `{$item.schedule.d{$i}}`
to generate something like this `{$item.schedule.d1}, {$item.schedule.d2},` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this that way:

In PHP:

```
$items = array();
$items['schedule']['d1'] = 'D1';
$items['schedule']['d2'] = 'D2';
$items['schedule']['d3'] = 'D3';
$smarty->assign('items',$items);
$smarty->display('index.tpl');
```

In index.tpl :

```
{$data = [1,2,3]}

{foreach $data as $value}
    {$items.schedule["d{$value}"]}<br />
{/foreach}
```

So in your case you should use `{$item.schedule["d{$i}"]}` syntax